# Linq Include of child object properties

Tags: c#, linq, include

A listedItem can be the parent object of device and vehicle. I want to include the properties of the child classes depending on what type of sub class is the object of.

```
var type = GetAllQuery(context).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

var listedItem = GetAllQuery(context)
                        .Include(x => x.Images)
                        .Include(x => x.User);

if (type.GetType().BaseType == typeof(Vehicle))
                    {

var vehicle = listedItem as IQueryable<Vehicle>;
                        return vehicle.Include(x => x.VehicleBrand).Include(x => x.VehicleModel).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

The same for device. vehicle is returning null for some reason and I cant seem to find out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Include in EF returns `ObjectQuery<T>`, you should not convert it to `Queryable`. use `as ObjectQuery<Vehicle>`. But you don't need to convert actually, it already of vehicle type

Also clean up the code, replace if with switch and better recommended using factory.

Something like this

```
public class IncludeConfiguratorFactory
    {
        public static IConfigurator Get<T>(T type)
        {
            switch (type.Name)
            {
                case "Vehicle":
                    return new VehicleConfigurator();
            }
        }
    }

    public class VehicleConfigurator : IConfigurator
    {

        #region IConfigurator Members

        public void Configure<T>(ObjectQuery<T> items ) where T : Vehicle
        {
            var vehicle = items.Include(x => x.VehicleBrand);
            vehicle = items.Include(x => x.VehicleModel);
        }

        #endregion
    }
    public interface IConfigurator
    {
        void Configure<T>(ObjectQuery<T> items);
    }
```

And call as

```
var listedItem = GetAllQuery(context).Include(x=>x.Images).Include(x => x.User);

        var provider = IncludeConfiguratorFactory.Get(itemType);
        provider.Configure(listedItem);
```

Please note: above code is not tested and may contain syntax errors

Comment: Thanks for the answer i m trying to make it work at the moment as I am not that great with generics. Up till now i changed this part 
`switch (typeof(T).Name)` 
I am having trouble in the Configure<T> as it is saying to consider using an explicit conversion instead of T

Comment: Whole error:

The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'Data.Repositories.VehicleConfigurator.Configure<T>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'Data.Repositories.IConfigurator.Configure<T>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.

Comment: Please investigate the type of listedItem and match the signature of configure. The code was just an idea.